# How could I manually translate a template I've downloaded?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, translation

This is my second day with wordpress and I would like to translate the whole website to my native language (Portuguese). I've translated a couple buttons and stuff, but it takes me a while to find where it is within the PHP codes, and, a friend of mine who works with wordpress, said it could be dangerous to alter the theme and cherry framework files.

I am looking for a tool/plugin where I can manually translate all the strings, and not use Google translate, as most plugins I've saw. Any tips?

Comment: I think what you want to do is called "localization" and wordpress has a l18n process for this. I agree, don't alter core files, your hard work could be overwritten in an update.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/localization  https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Comment: thanks, that looks like what I am looking for! I followed a tutorial posted by CherryFramework but I still can't make it work. I wonder if it's because I'm using WAMP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I managed to solve my problem with a WordPress plugin called [Say What](https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/). After installing it, it's pretty simple to use! For instance, I have this string on my template:

```
<?php _e('Search for: ','cherry');?>"<?php the_search_query(); ?>"
```

Then, on Say What plugin, all I gotta do is:

```
Original String = Search for: 
Text Domain = cherry
Replacement string = Buscar por:
```

It's working great! Thanks!